# How to interpret a "const unique_ptr"

Tags: c++, constants, unique-ptr

```
const unique_ptr<int> upi{new int{4}};
cout << ++*upi << '\n';
```

Seems `upi` is a `const smart pointer`. The `int` it points to can still be modified. What if I want to declare the `int` as `const`?

```
const unqiue_ptr<int> const upi{new int{4}};    //Error: duplicate const
```

Comment: `unique_ptr` is not const by default.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to make the integer `const` and not the pointer itself, right? Then you would have to write:

```
unique_ptr<const int> upi{new int{4}};
```

Answer (score 21):

Just in case someone is wondering what a const unique_ptr is:
It is a unique_ptr which will Not exchange the owned object during its lifetime.
However the owned object is not const.  Therefore a superb candidate for the Pimpl Idiom